# "RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type X has been deleted" in QGIS Plugin

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I cannot use the QGIS settings options, because I am getting the error as per below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mariuszk/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ORStools\proc\provider.py", line 69, in loadAlgorithms
    self.addAlgorithm(alg)
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type ORSdirectionsPointsLayersAlgo has been deleted
```

It applies not only for digitalizing, but also for colour changes and any other option.

[image]

How can I fix it? Or shall I do the reinstallation/upgrade to new version? Upgrade QGIS to version 3.10 didn't help.

Comment: The error seem to come from the ORS tool plugin, try to deactivate and/or reinstalling it

Comment: Yep, now the errror is gone :) SO If I will want to use OR plugin in the future, then I must forget about digitalizing then.

Comment: I've changed the title because this error is a general error for plugins which use `addAlgorithm` method in a for loop

Comment: I have the same error but the warning is : File C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\ProcessingToolbox.py", line 352, in executeAlgorithm if dlg.wasExecuted():. I have tried to clip a raster by a vector mask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Open `ORStools\proc\provider.py` file located in plugins folder via QGIS Python Editor (or in any editor).

- Goto line 69
- Remove for loop (two lines)

  ```
  for alg in self.alglist:
      self.addAlgorithm(alg)
  ```
- Add the following lines

  ```
  self.addAlgorithm(ORSdirectionsPointsLayersAlgo())
  self.addAlgorithm(ORSdirectionsPointsLayerAlgo())
  self.addAlgorithm(ORSdirectionsLinesAlgo())
  self.addAlgorithm(ORSisochronesLayerAlgo())
  self.addAlgorithm(ORSisochronesPointAlgo())
  self.addAlgorithm(ORSmatrixAlgo())
  ```

Reference: [Fix incorrect ownership of algorithms in processing provider](https://github.com/jdugge/BufferByPercentage/pull/14/commits/04269ff6b25433253259294eb480a10e4b353403)

**All plugins which use `addAlgorithm` method in a `for` loop give a similar error**, *dzetsaka* for example. All these (`ORS**`) are methods within `self.alglist`. Therefore, **solution differs from plugin to plugin**.